# How to found the mean of column in a matrix in R

Tags: r

hello i want to find the mean of a column in R
i have the table

```
x<- [
1 2 4
3 4 5
2 3 4
5 6 7]
```

and i want to find the mean of the first column!! A simple way that i used is with the

`summary(x)`

that saws the mean! but i don't want that. I want it with a comand.
Also if i want to take the mean of the second column where the first row numbers are bigger than 2 and at the same time the values of third column are bigger than 4? how i can do it?

Comment: -1 for not using R code and terminology in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not extract that column and take the mean??

```
> m <- matrix(1:10, nrow=5)
> mean(m[,1]) # mean of the first column
[1] 3

# mean of the second column conditional on values of column 3 are bigger than 4
> mean(x[x[,3]>4,2]) 
[1] 5
```

I don't understand what you mean with "...second column where the first row numbers are bigger than 2 ..." Anyway take a look at [`?"[`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) for learning how to subset a matrix and extract values from it.

Comment: Yes it's working! But i forgot to put inside my answer a NA in the last row 5=NA. if is like that how i can do it? mean(m[,1],NA.rm=FALSE))????

Comment: Use `mean(m[,1], na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: `?colMeans` could also be interesting.